# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.appname' when running Django tests

Tags: django, testing

When trying to run my tests using either `./manage.py test` or `pytest`, all of the apps in my Django project fail their tests with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.appname'`.  However, when running with `./manage.py test app.tests` (if the tests are in a dedicated tests directory), they do progress beyond a Module Not Found error.

I think there is something wrong with my configuration that leads to this error but I have no idea where to poke to try fixing this: I'm not seeing anything that makes PyCharm yell at me when I look at any testing module nor when looking at Settings.py

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the `__init__.py` file from the `project`.

e.g.

```
project/
    - appname
       ...
    ...
    __init__.py    # Remove this one.
```

Comment: Did the trick.  Now to debug all the other learning opportunities I set up for myself to get these accursed tests to run.

Comment: Worked for me too. But for some reason Django keeps re-creating the file.